# How do I catch a subprocess.call error with Python?

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I'm trying to download a specific Docker image, where the user will input a version. However, if the version doesn't exist, Docker will throw an error.

I'm using `subprocess.call` to pipe to the Terminal from Python 3.

Sample code:

```
from subprocess import call
containerName = input("Enter Docker container name: ")
swVersion = input("Enter software version: ")

call(["docker", "run", "--name", "{}".format(containerName), 
      "--detach", "--publish", "8080:8080", "user/software:{}".format(swVersion)])
```

If the version isn't found, docker will output in the Terminal:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for user/software:8712378 not found.
```

How do I catch this error within the Python script?

Something along the lines of:

```
try:
    call(["docker", "run", "--name", "{}".format(containerName), "--detach", "--publish", "8080:8080", "user/software:{}".format(swVersion)])
except:
    # How do I catch the piped response code here?`
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the error message when it fails?  Also, to format code blocks, preface the line(s) with 4 spaces instead of using backticks.

Comment: Well yes, I want to catch the error so I can re-prompt the user to input a valid version, if that makes sense :)

Comment: That depends on what "catch the error" is, if you just want to have an exception raised if the program doesn't work, use `check_call` instead of `call`, if you want to get the string written to `stderr` then you should do it a different way

Comment: I haven't had a look at check_call, will read about it. By catch the error, I mean just printing an error message to the user, and re-prompt for a valid software number. The error message is a hand-crafted string.

Comment: So the question still remains, do you want to get the string written to `stderr` by the program you're calling or not?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then no, I just want to catch it in the python script, not in bash? :) Appears like I can catch any error with check_call instead, thanks - that's something to work with at least!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Popen` function of `subprocess` to grab the `stderr` and print in python console, as [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) says for `subprocess.call`

> Note Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that
>   can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with
>   the communicate() method when you need pipes.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["docker", "run", "--name", "{}".format(containerName), "--detach", "--publish", "8080:8080", "user/software:{}".format(swVersion)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess_flags)
proc.wait()
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()

if proc.returncode != 0:
    print(stderr)
else:
    print("success")
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are fine with the program writing its output to `stderr` and you not directly interacting with it, the easiest way to do what you are asking is to use `check_call` instead of `call`.  `check_call` will raise an exception if the command it's running exits with anything other than `0` as its status.

```
try:
    check_call(["docker", "run", "--name", "{}".format(containerName), "--detach", "--publish", "8080:8080", "user/software:{}".format(swVersion)])
except CalledProcessError:
    print("That command didn't work, try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above with checking the return code works but the more pythonic way would be to catch an exception like:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["docker", "run", "--name", "{}".format(containerName), "--detach", "--publish", "8080:8080", "user/software:{}".format(swVersion)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess_flags)
    proc.wait()
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()

except calledProcessError as err:
    print("Error ocurred: " + err.stderr)
```

calledProcessError is the error caught by the Popen class.

If you want to catch the frequent errors on OS or system level (e.g. file/directory doesn't exist), add the following exceptions:

```
except OSError as e:
    print ("OSError > ",e.errno)
    print ("OSError > ",e.strerror)
    print ("OSError > ",e.filename)

except:
    print ("Error > ",sys.exc_info()[0])
```

If you want to return a return code, you should do that explicitly instead of print()ing it. Write after the last except statement and on the same indentation as the try statement:

```
return True
```

If you want to return a message, you can use the Response object:

```
return Response ("Success Message")
```